# Yii : Show Post In category

Tags: php, yii

I Used this code For Showing post in category

```
 public function actionCategoryList($id)
{ 
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(

        'condition'=>'status='.Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
        'order'=>'create_time DESC',

    ));
    if(isset($_GET['tag']))
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('tags',$_GET['tag']);


            $criteria->addSearchCondition('id_category',$id);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['postsPerPage'],
        ),
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

But the category ID 10 View Post after addition of the categories in the category ID 1 is still displayed
For example, the image below:
[image]
Category ID is 10, but in addition to the display

www.mysite.com/categoryList/10

ID 1 is still displayed in the categories
www.mysite.com/categoryList/1

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is url-manager and you have two solutions:

1. you should use `www.mysite.com/categoryList/id/1` instead of `www.mysite.com/categoryList/1`.
2. If you want to use `www.mysite.com/categoryList/1` url, you need to define a rule in url-manager:

   ```
   'urlManager'=>array(
       'urlFormat'=>'path',
       'showScriptName'=>false,
       'caseSensitive'=>false, 
       'rules'=>array(

           'categoryList/<id:\d+>'=>'categoryLis/id',
            ....
       ),
   ),
   ```

Comment: I ,did it, But THIS WAY ISN'T TRUE :( - my rules is -->            'categoryList/<id:\d+>'=>'categoryLis/id',